# How to delete a row from a datagrid based upon a value from another in WPF

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I am new to WPF, but I would like to know if someone can show me how to delete a row in one datagrid based upon a selection from another. The application uses C# and MVVM design pattern. Can anyone help?

Thanks